# String getting parsed incorrectly by DecimalFormat with different locales

Tags: java, locale, decimalformat

Code:-

```
((DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","US"))).parse("0.5")
```

output: 0.5

Code :-

```
((DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es","CN"))).parse("0.5")
```

output : 5

I am using the `DecimalFormat` to format the string into number, but it is somehow not giving the expected results for different locales. 
Please help me with getting same output for all locales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inputting "es" in Locale, so you are parsing it as a Spanish way to parse the String. In Spanish, the decimal separator is a comma. So 0.5 becomes 5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the correct decimal separator for the given locale so since it is comma for Spanish you need to have

```
 ((DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es","CN"))).parse("0,5")
```

But of course if "0.5" is the correct format then you need to change your locale instead to one that matches the format